# Linux says the screen is dead but it doesn't close it

Tags: bash, debian, gnu-screen

I'm trying to learn how to work with "screen" tool.

I have 2 additional screens.

```
ixnomad@NomadMachine:~$ screen -ls 
There are screens on:
        1037111.SYS_INFO        (06/03/22 17:09:38)     (Detached)
        1037094.CHECK_CONNECTION        (06/03/22 17:08:40)     (Detached)
2 Sockets in /run/screen/S-ixnomad.
```

Then I'm trying to close them (I don't want to open them again)

```
ixnomad@NomadMachine:~$ kill -9 1037111
```

But then it actually doesn't disappear, Linux says it's probably(??) dead, and I should "wipe" it.

```
ixnomad@NomadMachine:~$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
        1037094.CHECK_CONNECTION        (06/03/22 17:08:39)     (Detached)
        1037111.SYS_INFO        (06/03/22 13:28:42)     (Dead ???)
Remove dead screens with 'screen -wipe'.
2 Sockets in /run/screen/S-ixnomad.
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't know how I can close a screen without entering to it, closing a running process in there, typing "exit", etc..
Is there any command just to close it?
Something like

```
screen -close(??) 1037111
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509677/kill-detached-screen-session

Comment: you would use `screen -S -X [session number] quit`

Comment: @Esther it says "Cannot exec '1037111': No such file or directory".

Comment: well it's already dead, so you will need `screen -wipe` for this one, but the next time you can use the above command on a `detached` screen and it will kill it entirely

Comment: I've done that, but it happens when I'm trying to use -S -X quit to a working screen. (It's detached)

Comment: @Esther Thank you. The mistake was that it must've been

`screen -S [session number] -X quit`

A bit different order.

Comment: You have tagged `debian` but not a ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

This problem stems from killing screen with `-9` (`SIGKILL`) rather than a more "polite" signal like `SIGTERM`.  `SIGKILL` tells the kernel to remove the process from its tables, which does not give the process time to clean itself up.  Most other signals go to the process itself, so it has a chance to handle it gracefully.

(A short side discussion:) It's a bad habit to start with `kill -9 ...`; experts recommend trying first without the signal (it defaults to `SIGTERM`).  If that does not work, it means the process is uninterruptible or intentionally ignoring that signal.  Only then should you resort to `SIGKILL`.

You probably wish to kill screen's child process anyway.  When you do that, screen is notified of its death and exits cleanly.  That is what the `kill -S [session] -X quit` command that Esther mentioned in the comments does.

Or, as also mentioned above, if you do end up with a dead screen session, `screen -wipe` tells the coordinating screen process to clean it up.